# Установка галочки в чекбокс при клике по слову, и ее удаление, при клике по другому

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Смог найти, как установить галочку в чекбокс при клике по пункту списка, но нужно, чтобы при клике по другому пункту галочка из предыдущего удалялась. Радиокнопки использовать не могу, поэтому приходится изменять работу чекбокса.
Как использовать `...('input').removeAttr('checked');` у всех пунктов кроме того по которому кликнул??

```js
$(function() {
  $('.leaf').click(function() {
    $(this).find('input').attr('checked', 'true')
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="facetapi">
  <li class="leaf">
    <input type="checkbox" class="facetapi-checkbox" checked="true">
    <a href="#" class="inactive">Wi-Fi (5)</a>
  </li>
  <li class="leaf">
    <input type="checkbox" class="facetapi-checkbox">
    <a href="#" class="inactive">Телефон (5)</a>
  </li>
  <li class="leaf">
    <input type="checkbox" class="facetapi-checkbox">
    <a href="#" class="inactive">Интернет (5)</a>
  </li>
  <li class="leaf">
    <input type="checkbox" class="facetapi-checkbox">
    <a href="#" class="inactive">Душ (5)</a>
  </li>
  <li class="leaf">
    <input type="checkbox" class="facetapi-checkbox">
    <a href="#" class="inactive">Холодильник (5)</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: в чем проблема с input radio + label?

Answer (score 1):

Для изменения состояния чекбокса используйте [*свойство*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) [checked](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2), а не атрибут

Например

```
$(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
```

Для того, чтобы был выбран только один - нужно перед выставлением текущему, сбросить все остальные

```
$('.leaf').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('ul') // выбираем текущий список
           .find('input:checkbox') // выбираем все чекбоксы
           .prop('checked', false); // сбрасываем все чекбоксы в списке
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);// устанавливаем для выбранного элемента
});
```

Comment: да, только возможность переключения я все равно реализовать не знаю как, а работает скрипт и с атрибутом может неправильно но работает.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, в итоге выбранным должен быть только один чекбокс? Если кликнули по уже выбранному чекбоксу он должен сброситься?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.facetapi .leaf').click(function() {
    $('.facetapi input:checked').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obqNXo